# python, json type write - how can i use \n on dictionary value?

Tags: python, json

i create dic type value, and here is my code

```
date = ["2015 1 3", "2015 1 3", "2015 1 3"]
des  = ["btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits...", "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2 ...", "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain ..."]

for i in range(3) :
    dic = {"date":date[i], "description":des[i]}

with open('j.json', 'a', encoding='UTF-8-sig') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(dic, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    print (json.dumps(dic, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False) )
```

when i print this value, it works fine but f.write this 'dic' value, there is no \n on each tuple

here is result of print (dic)

```
{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits..."
}
{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2 ..."
}
{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain ..."
}
```

and my json file is saved like this,

```
{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits..."
}{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2 ..."
}{
  "date": "2015 1 3",
  "description": "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain ..."
}
```

how can i save this end of } , and \n { ?

Comment: `f.write('\n')`?

Comment: Please don't include pictures of code, ideally it should be in text. But what you're trying to create is JSON Lines

Comment: Try removing `indent=2` and just dump the raw string

Comment: @zvone it doesn't works.

Comment: @roganjosh i edited it.  and how can i create new json line?

Comment: Did you try removing `indent=2`?

Comment: @roganjosh yes, when i removing indent, there is no '\n' on my json file. so i realize dic type value printed by 'each tuple'  so simply add '\n' is answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `\n` to end of each line. Here's how to write:

```
outputFile=open('somefile.txt','a')
for i in range(3) :
    dic = {"date":date[i], "description":des[i]}
    outputFile.write(json.dumps(dic) + '\n')
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
date = ["2015 1 3", "2015 1 3", "2015 1 3"]
des  = ["btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits...", "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2 ...", "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain ..."]

dicts = []
for i in range(3) :
    dic = {"date":date[i], "description":des[i]}
    dicts.append(dic)

file=open('json.txt','a')
for i in dicts:
    file.write(json.dumps(i))
    file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Similar idea as psychoCoder. -

```
import json

date = ["2015 1 3", "2015 1 3", "2015 1 3"]
des  = ["btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits...", "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2 ...", "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain ..."]

with open('j.json', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(3) :
        dic = {"date":date[i], "description":des[i]}
        f.write(json.dumps(dic, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
        f.write("\n")
        print (json.dumps(dic, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False) )
```